# No line break in enumerate while using textcolor

Tags: color, line-breaking

Can someone explain why LaTeX is not inserting a line break ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\textcolor{red}{webServiceURL}/\textcolor{red}{version}/devices/\textcolor{red}{deviceLibraryIdentifier}/registrations/\textcolor{red}{passTypeIdentifier}?passesUpdatedSince=\textcolor{red}{tag}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Replacing all instances of `/` with `\slash`  doesn't appear to make a difference.

Comment: don't show a snippet, show a complete example (and show also how the behaviour changes without the color).

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code to make it minimally compilable.

Comment: In what way is this related to color? If I use `webServiceURL/version/devices/deviceLibraryIdentifier/registrations/passTypeIdentifier?passesUpdatedSince=tag` I see the same line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've come across is not related, *per se*, to the use of `\textcolor`. Instead, it's caused by the fact that the input line contains no spaces but lots of nonstandard words, resulting in TeX somehow going off-track and producing a massively overfull line.

The remedy? Load the `xurl` package and wrap the sub-string closest to the line break -- here: passTypeIdentifier -- in a `\url` wrapper.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,xurl}
\urlstyle{same}

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault % just for this example
\begin{document}

\textcolor{blue}{bad}

\textcolor{red}{webServiceURL}/\textcolor{red}{version}/devices/\textcolor{red}{deviceLibraryIdentifier}/registrations/\textcolor{red}{passTypeIdentifier}?passesUpdatedSince=\textcolor{red}{tag}

\medskip
\textcolor{blue}{good}

\textcolor{red}{webServiceURL}/\textcolor{red}{version}/devices/\textcolor{red}{deviceLibraryIdentifier}/registrations/\textcolor{red}{\url{passTypeIdentifier}}?passesUpdatedSince=\textcolor{red}{tag}
\end{document}
```